# What is a good strategy for handling large lists on websites without a pager?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

#### Scenario

I have web interface (in a large web application) that allows a user to make a connection between two very large lists.

List A - 40,000+ items
List B - 1,000+ items
List C - Contains a list of items in b that are connected to the selected item in list A

#### The Code

Here is a rough [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spkL223m/8/) of the current behavior minus the ajax update of the database.

Here is the primary functionality (only here because stack overflow requires a code snippet for jsfiddle links).

```
$('.name-listb input').add('.name-listc input').click(function (e) {
    var lista_id = $('.name-lista input:checked').val();
    var listb_id = $(this).val();
    var operation = $(this).prop('checked') ? 'create' : 'delete';
    var $listb = $('.name-listb .checkbox-list');
    var $listc = $('.name-listc .checkbox-list');

    if (operation == 'create') {
        $listb.find('input[value=' + listb_id + ']').prop('checked', true);
        // Ajax request to add checked item.
        $new_item = $listb.find('input[value=' + listb_id + ']').parents('.option-group').clone();
        $listc.append($new_item);
    } else if (operation == 'delete') {
            console.log('hello list delete');
        $listb.find('input[value=' + listb_id + ']').prop('checked', false);
        // Ajax request to remove checked item.
        $listc.find('input[value=' + listb_id + ']').parents('.option-group').remove();
    }
});
```

### The Problem

The requirements do not allow for me to use an auto complete field or pager. But the current page takes way too long to load (between 1 and 5sec depending on caching). Also the JS behaviors are attached to all 40k+ items which will cause problems on lower performance computers (Tested on a newish $200 consumer special and the computer was crippled by the JS). There is also (not on JS fiddle but the final product) a filter that filters the list down based on text input.

### The Question

What is a good strategy for handling this scenario?

### My Idea

My first thought was to create a sort of document view architecture. A JavaScript list that adds items to the top and bottom as the user scrolls and dumps items off the other end when the list reaches a certain size. To filter I would dump the whole list and obtain a new list of filtered items like an auto-complete but it would be able to scroll and add items using ajax. But this is very complicated. I was hoping someone might have a better idea or a jquery plugin that already uses this approach.

#### Update

Lista is 70K Fixed
Listb is User generated and will span between 1k-70k.
That said just optimizing the JS with the excellent feedback of using delegates (which will make life 10x more awesome), won't be enough. Still need to limit the visible list.

#### Your Ideas?

Comment: 40k DOM elements might be large, but not unmanageable. Why in the world are you attaching callbacks to each one? Delegate.

Comment: There are a few optimizations that you could make to possibly improve the performance without changing functionality, such as using event delegation so that you have 1 or two event handlers rather than 40k plus.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what "Delegate" means?

Comment: [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: `$('.name-lista').on('click','input',function() { ... });` rather than `$('.name-lista input').click()`

Comment: @danielson317 to delegate means to attach the handler to a single containing element, and then invoke the actions through that. ie. `$('.name-listb input').parent().on('click', '.name-listb input', handlerFunction);`

Comment: Looping over 40k iterations and doing nothing has a small delay, add in binding an event handler and it begins to add up quickly.

Comment: @prodigitalson - the code in your comment is only marginally better - it has to query all the inputs (40k) first and then get the parent element.

Comment: @Adam Didnt look at his fiddle so i have no idea what the DOM structure is... the important point is to hit that singlular parent element and attach the handler to there. Also your comment which takes into account his actual dom was not there when i began cmmenting :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've encountered this issue on numerous projects before and one solution that's both easy to implement and well performing is using something like [Infinity.js](http://airbnb.io/infinity/).
To summarize shortly, Infinity, like many other *"infinite scroll"* libraries, allows you to render only a small part of the actual list that should be visible (or should be visible soon), thus reducing the strain on the browser tremendously. You can see a simple live demo [over here](http://airbnb.io/infinity/demo-on.html), check the first link for the API reference.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see any ajax callbacks in the api. I'm not sure from the supplied documentation how to pull the data via ajax on demand instead of loading all of it up front. Is this strictly a front end solution?

Comment: @danielson317 You can provide the optional method `lazy` when initializing the `ListView` to load items on demand (as opposed to loading all of them). This method can utilize an Ajax call, for example, when used with other methods on the list.

Comment: Is their an example of that behavior somewhere? The documentation is very sparse and the demo provides no code examples.

Comment: I don't think Infinity provides an example for that, but some alternative libraries do. The keyword you're looking for is _"infinite scrolling"_.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with http://jscroll.com/. It has much better documentation and is a much simpler implementation. Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score -3):

This is not impossible to do, the trick is NOT to load all that stuff onto the DOM because it will wreck any Java Script Engine.

The answer is using the [d3js](http://d3js.org/) base library, which is the king amongst sorting extremely large data on client side, whether it is tabular or graphical. When I first saw it it had 4 examples, now there are pages and pages.

This is one of the first examples [provided by d3, crossfilter.](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/)

The dataset if **5.3megabytes!** And it filters data in milliseconds, and it promises to sort millions of rows without a performance loss.

Comment: I didn't down-vote your answer, but I think the main issue is that you seem to be addressing a different issue than the one the question asked about.

Comment: Sorting massive amounts of data without crippling the browser. Yea.. d3js.... you just need to rework your implementation. Maybe even look into Angular or Knock out, since you doing some funky dynamic selector building, with d3js as the sorting engine?

Comment: You don't have to explain your reasoning to me, I'm merely speculating about the down-voters.

Comment: Yea... sorry.. I thought you were the OP.